# Error deploying to Azure through git (bitbucket hosted git repo)

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket

This morning, I went to our website to find out this : The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

I then went to windows azure management portal, and then it told me that it cannot connect to bitbucket. I went to bitbucket to see if it was up, everything was fine. I also pull changes from bitcuket and it worked like a charm.

Now azure website keep nagging me with "Could not link the Bitbucket repository 'ZZZ website' with Windows Azure web site 'ZZZ'.

All the statuses on http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/ are green, and I have no idea what to do to bring my site back on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One hour just passed by, and Microsoft Folks seems to have corrected the issue, as I was able to add the bitbucket repo to the azure website, without changing anything on azure nor bitbucket.

Answer (score 0):

1.Connect your Azure Web Site FTP then delete all items in repository folder.

2.On your Azure Portal Dashboard click Reset Your Publish Profile Credentials.

Thats all.

Note: After Reset Your Publish Profile Credentials FTP connection password will be changed.