# Deploying Bitbucket to Azure

Tags: git, azure, deployment, bitbucket

I have a Bitbucket repository that I'd like to link to Windows Azure.  I'm able to click "Set up deployment from source control", grant access to Azure, and view the screen that displays my repositories and asks for the branch to deploy.  Everytime I select the repository and tell it to deploy the "master" branch, it fails with

> Could not link the Bitbucket repository 'xxx' with Windows Azure web site 'xxxx'.

This application is a ASP.NET Web form application written in .NET 2.0.  I do not see any errors logs in the Azure FTP.  I've attempted to revoke Azure authentication in Bitbucket and retry with NO luck.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it a reproducible issue? (because of http://stackoverflow.com/a/19248504/6309)

Comment: It looks to be a known issue with .NET 2.0/3.5.  I will accept David's answer below when verified.

Comment: @david, was this rolled out?  One month later, I still have issues.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with this when the site is running as .NET 2.0/3.5. The fix should be available sometime in the next few weeks.